# Checking that mm is valid before using it (C)

Tags: c, dereference

Section of code:

```
unsigned long code_memory(void)
{
    unsigned long totalmem=0;

    unsigned long thismem;
    struct task_struct *thechild;
    for_each_process(thechild)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO “pid %d”,thechild->pid);
        thismem=thechild->mm->end_code - thechild->mm->start_code;
        printk(KERN_INFO “ has codesize %lu.\n”,thismem);
        totalmem=totalmem+thismem;
    }
    return totalmem;
}
```

I can't figure out how to check that mm is valid, running the entire code results with it crashing.

Comment: If your desire is to decide between whether `mm` has been set to a null pointer or a pointer to an object, you can test whether it is not null (points to an object) with `if (thechild->mm) …`. If your desire is to decide between whether `mm` has been set to some valid value or has not been set (initialized) at all, that is not supported by the C standard, and you need to design your code so that it is always initialized before being used.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Definitely had a giant brain fart in correcting that error.

Comment: I would suggest that while `if (thechild->mm) ...` accomplishes the task in this case, explicitly checking for `NULL` is more expressive of your intent. `if (thechild->mm == NULL) ...`